# Why the cachebusting it doesn't always work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple application built with Gulp. Every time I do a build I change the names of the js and css files (file name example: myApp-v2021-02-22_21-12-29.js) and obviously I change the reference in the HTML.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/myApp-v2021-02-22_21-12-29.css">
<script src="./js/myApp-v2021-02-22_21-12-29.js"></script>
```

Yet sometimes I'm forced to do a hard refresh to let the browser know that the files have changed. Could you suggest me something?

Comment: Maybe the HTML file is cached and thus the browser loads the old CSS and JS files?

Comment: I agree with @FelixKling point, you can check in console whether name of the file is changing in link/script tag or not

Comment: Yes, of course the HTML is also cached... so how could I force the HTML to refresh?

Comment: Use server-side metadata, such as ETags and Last Modified headers to do the work for you.

Comment: What if the content is static and if I use a simple web server?